# How to fix An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Tags: vb.net

> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component
>   with CLSID {4EC4272E-2E6F-4EEB-91D0-EBC4D58E8DEE} failed due to the
>   following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>   The below line of code causes the exception

**Dim WiaManager As New WIALib.WiaClass**

I am  a newbie in c#. I am trying to build an ocr application that reads the image and converts it into a document. When I try to scan a document I keep getting this exception.

Any suggestions to fix this would be really appreciated.

Comment: COM component needs to be registered prior to using in your application. Exception clearly states `Class not registered`. So register your library using `regsvr32` command from command prompt.

Comment: @ Irshad: well thank you so much for your quick reply....how can I do that could you please shed some more light on it??

Comment: refer this; https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx